# Can I create some kind of "mediator" between Form data and a form control?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a model that has a custom property type `TimeSpan`. I want to edit that in a `[form]` using a `kendo-timepicker` but that expects a `Date` object.

Is there a way I can create a directive that will intercept between the control and the underlying ngControl so that I can convert between `TimeSpan` and `Date`?

I'd rather not have to create a new class that looks the same as the model but with a different property type.

Comment: Usually I use a pair of controls instead of 1 in such cases. They can be bound to each other via one-way or two-way binding through valueChanges observables. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to add an additional variable where I save the mapped form. So something like this:

```
mappedForm={};
constructor(....){...}


ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
     form.property =  parseInt(form.property, null);
     this.mappedForm = form;
   })    
}
```

In this case I am mapping a string to a number but you can use the 'as' keyword to map more complex data structures. Also depending on your case you can just use map and have an observable with the correct value instead of subscribing like I did. Also be aware that mappedForm is only a snapshot of the value of the form and do not contain it's other properties.

**EDIT IF YOU WANT TO RE-UPDATE THE FORM CONTROL**

If you want to reset the form control value you probably need to use an auxiliary boolean so you don`t fall in an infinite loop.

```
ngOnInit() {
let isFirst = false;
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
  form.prop = parseInt(form.prop , null);//replace with you mapping
  if (isFirst) {
    this.myForm.patchValue(form);
    isFirst = !isFirst;
  } 
})
}
```

Comment: That would set the value in the form, but how would you intercept the reading of the value back as a date for the control?

Comment: I think if you use the patchValue or setValue methods of the form control in the value changes it would create an infinite loop. Maybe you can use some auxiliary booleans to make sure it runs only on real changes.